# Get Username and Photo from JWT Token, Python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, jwt

I'm trying to create an api call that will return the username of the individual that logged in as well as their photo. I am logging in via an app and attempting to fire off that api call when the user logs in.

I am using the rest_framework_simplejwt to sign in and assign a token then return that token via the app to use to access data in various api calls.

Right now
 This what I have so far:

```
url(r'^api/token/$', TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

Once the verification has happened and the user gets a token back, I'm going to fire off this api call.

Api Call:

```
@csrf_exempt
def current_user(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':

        driver = JWTAuthentication().authenticate(request)[0].driver

    driverInfo = request.user.get_full_name()
    return JsonResponse({"success": driverInfo})
```

Here are my serializers:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super(MyTokenObtainPairSerializer, cls).get_token(user)

        # Add custom claims
        token['name'] = user.name
        # ...

        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

It's only returning the token and nothing else. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can custom your Django REST Framework JWT response,

if you use JWT plugin for DRF from getblimp,
refer to its documentation [1]

JWT plugin for DRF has additional settings with key **JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER**

so you add JWT_AUTH configuration on settings.py and declare you function which you want to use as handler of JWT response payload.

there's an example of user info via UserSerializer at the documentation.

[1]http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/